# Rafial Basis Function ANN: grid search error

Tags: python, keras, neural-network

I am triying to develop a RBF ANN model to predict a continuous variable. I am implementing the model with the iris dataset as a test. When I try to find the best hyperparameters for my rb function (gaussian) I constantly get an error related with `x` and `y` must have the same dtype, got tf.float32 != tf.int32.
Call arguments received by layer "dense_404" (type Dense):
• inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(None, 3), dtype=float32)

My data is
X_train_scaled
sepal width (cm)    petal length (cm)   petal width (cm)
0   1.203658    -1.562535   -1.312603
1   2.992376    -1.276006   -1.045633
2   0.085709    0.385858    0.289218
and y_train_scaled
sepal length (cm)
0   -1.473937
1   -0.133071
2   1.085898
[..]

I've tryied to change the type of both datasets to float32, float64...

Thank you,

```
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from keras import backend as K
from keras.models import Sequential
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.initializers import RandomUniform
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler, OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

```
X = df[['sepal width (cm)', 'petal length (cm)', 'petal width (cm)', 'species']]
y = df['sepal length (cm)']

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
```

I've standarize the data and put the categorical columns as One Hot encoder.

```
def gaussian_activation(x, mu=0, sigma=1):
    return K.exp(-K.square(x - mu) / (2 * K.square(sigma)))

def create_model(mu=0, sigma=1):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(10, input_dim=X_train_scaled.shape[1], activation=lambda x: gaussian_activation(x, mu=mu, sigma=sigma), kernel_initializer=RandomUniform(minval=-2, maxval=2)))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))
    model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')
    return model

model = KerasRegressor(build_fn=create_model, epochs=100, batch_size=32, verbose=0)

param_grid = {'mu': [0, 0.5, 1], 'sigma': [0.1, 0.5, 1]}  

grid = GridSearchCV(estimator=model, param_grid=param_grid, cv=3, error_score='raise')
grid_result = grid.fit(X_train_scaled, y_train_scaled)

means = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
stds = grid_result.cv_results_['std_test_score']
params = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
best_index = np.argmax(means)
best_mu = param_grid['mu'][best_index]
best_sigma = param_grid['sigma'][best_index]

print("Best value of mu:", best_mu)
print("Best value of sigma:", best_sigma)
print("Mean squared error:", means[best_index])
```